# What's the right design pattern for a factory like pattern but different parameters?

Tags: design-patterns, factory-pattern

Context: Let's say I have an uninstaller. For the different things I want to uninstall (such as reg keys and files), I'll need objects to perform those actions. I anticipate having an IUninstallAction interface, with a Uninstall function. Then my RegistryUninstallAction and FileUninstallAction classes could implement IUninstallAction.

Problem: The RegistryUninstallAction constructor needs different parameters than the FileUninstallAction constructor. And other classes implementing IUninstallAction may also need different parameters.

Question: What is the appropriate design pattern for this scenario? My first thought was the factory pattern but because of the different constructor parameters, this seems like a poor fit.

Comment: It's unclear to me why just calling the constructors of the various actions isn't sufficient. Start doing it the simplest way you can imagine, and use patterns if they emerge from the code.

Comment: I was more asking if there is an appropriate design pattern for this scenario. The answer may be no, based on the above constraints.